# Maintaining uniform horizontal CSS padding across components

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm building a webpage with React and TailwindCSS. Each section of the page is a separate React Component, but I would like to ensure that all sections have uniform horizontal padding and a max-width at which point, the content is centred and doesn't grow with the screen. I created a component which I add to each section which adds the padding, and centres the content when necessary.

```
const Container = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <div className="grid place-items-center w-full px-[5%] lg:px-[2%] xl:px-[6%]">
      <div className="max-w-[120rem]  w-full">
        {children}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Is there a way to achieve the same same effect without the component that'll be repeated in every section?

Answer (score 0):

You can use map:

```
const children = [
    <Component1/>,
    <Component2/>,
    <Component3/>,
]
childrenJSX = children.map((child) => <div className="grid place-items-center w-full px-[5%] lg:px-[2%] xl:px-[6%]">
        <div className="max-w-[120rem]  w-full">
            {child}
        </div>
    </div>)
return (childrenJSX)
```